# How to access elements of vector of pairs using a pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std-pair

I am creating a vector of int pairs to create 28 domino pieces. After creating a piece, how do I access it using the pointer? I tried x->first, x[0]->first, x.first. I seem to be misunderstanding something.
Here is the code, for example, how would I access the first element in the pair I just created.

```
vector < pair <int, int>>* x;

x = new vector<pair <int, int>>;

x->push_back(make_pair(1, 3));
```

Comment: Pro tip: Don't use a `vector < pair <int, int>>*`.  Just use a `vector < pair <int, int>>`.  having pointers to standard containers is generally pointless.

Comment: [The general rule of thumb for using `new` is don't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: This logic of using pointers to address data in containers is old-fashioned C style. If you want to code in C++, you should  follow the advice of @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica and others and just don't do it.

Comment: There are certain cases where dynamic allocation of a standard container on the heap is necessary, and for that use a smart pointer (not new); but stack allocation at compile time is usually a preferable option, as others suggest. C++ lets you decide which is best.

Answer (score 2):

Since you made a pointer, you need to dereference it:

`(*x)[0].first`

or

`x->operator[](0).first`

or

`x->at(0).first`    (to get bounds checking)

But don't make a pointer to the vector. Simply use `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> x;` and you can do `x[0].first` directly.

Comment: Or use `x->at(0).first` to get bounds checking.

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious reason to use a pointer here is if you want to be able to dynamically create new domino sets at runtime, say by calling a function. For that, using a smart pointer is the way to go. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>> dominoFactory() {
    //note syntax with make_unique
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>> vec = 
                    std::make_unique<std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>>();
    //make a pair object to serve as a loader for the vector
    std::pair<int,int> temp;
    for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            temp = std::make_pair(i, j);
            vec->push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    //transfer ownership to a unique_ptr in the calling function:
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>> pieces = dominoFactory();
    //dereference the pointer to access the vector internals
    for (auto x : *pieces) {
        //use pair methods to display each value
        std::cout << x.first << " : " << x.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This approach should be robust against memory leaks and is much preferable to using new.